# self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; create an extra gap after navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Let me explain my situation first. I set the `UINavigationBar` color in my `appDelegate` Like:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:87.0f/255.0f blue:10.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
```

Now in my some `viewController` the `translucent` of `UINavigationBar` set as `YES`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

That's why there is a shade over my `UINavigationBar`. It wasn't showing the exact color. As a solution, I set `translucent` from `YES` to `NO`. It is showing the exact color now, But I am facing that some of my view completely gone from my interface. Here, let me tell you one thing that, so many of views here, is positioned by programmatically, so I am afraid I can't just move every of my `viewController`s view 64 px high. Just wondering is there any solution to solve the thing. I try with `opaque`, but no luck. If any one understand my problem please share the solution if you have. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `I am facing that some of my view completely gone from my interface`. What do you mean?

Comment: If AutoLayout is enable than this situation is happens. You need to recalculate or recreate constraints in Storyboard by settings `translucent = NO`  in UINavigationController of view controller. After this you will get exact view rendering constraints.

Comment: @Wongzigii Thanks for your comment. What I mean is, say I have a view at the bottom of my `viewController`, but after set `translucent = YES` it goes bottom of my view (I mean out of interface that couldn't be visualized any more), but it comes back, it I set it `NO` again.

Comment: @Kampai Thanks for commenting. But, Here the `Autolayout` is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS7 if you use a translucent bar ( in `UINavigationController` or `UITabbarController`) the hosted view controller has as default behavior to extend under them. If you say to set the bar as translucent the color of it it will be a combination of the view under it and bat color. That is normal and the only way is to set translucency to no or apply a background image to navigation bar.
Applying frames manually will lead to unexpected result under auto layout, you must use constraints.
**[UPDATE]**
To create a background image from a solid color you can use that method, the image is 1px square, but there is no problem because it can be stretched or tiled to cover the entire area:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor*) color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return colorImage;
}
```

If you see and extra gap is probably because you have also set automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInset to YES, try setting it NO. This property add and extra inset to your view or your vfirst view subview if it inherits from a `UIScrollView`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, you are suggesting to use `UIImage` as `UINavigationBar` and set it through `CGRect` and then the `translucent = NO` will not occur any effect of it?

Comment: I'm suggesting you to use an image as background image of UINavigationBar  - backgroundImageForBarMetrics: , no need to set frames or something. As far as I remember traslucency is automatically set to NO when you set a background image.

Comment: Absolutely perfect (y)....You have saved a lot of time. :D
Thanks man. Have a great day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its late, but i face same issue, and i resolved it by making UINavigationbar none on Viewcontroller in storyboard, and resized the view to start from 0,0